# Get lines between exact two lines matching with sed command in shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have one file in Linux which have data something like

```
Line1A
Line2
Line1
Line3
Line4
```

And I want to get lines between Line1 and Line4 i.e. Line3.
I used following linux command in shell.

```
Sed -n -e "/Line1/,/Line4/p" myFile.txt
```

This gives me following output

```
Line2
Line1
Line3
```

Above output is because sed searched lines like contains and not exact line matching.
Is there a way to get string between extract line matching ?

Comment: What version of `sed` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sed the `^` represents line beginning, the `$` represents line ending.

```
sed -n "/^Line1$/,/^Line4$/p"
```

Your sed is strange, this sed command should output the lines between the patterns including the patterns themselves. Anyway, shortly tested at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/hnZ0HG).

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand you well what you are searching for is something like `sed -n -e '/^Line\(1\|4\)$/p'`.

You can use '^' to say you want search pattern to match start of line an '$' to match end of line.

Comment: Nice to see your quick response on this. Examples which I shared here is just an sample one. For with my actual data, there is nothing like Line1 or Line2. My question was how we can get lines between two exact lines using sed command?

Comment: @Navnath Sorry, I misunderstood your question,

Answer (score 0):

Try awk.

When you specify range using /../,/../, the match will include the boundaries as well.
But in your case, you don't need it, so you have to do little manipulation.

```
$ cat navnath.txt
Line1A
Line2
Line1
Line3
Line4
$  awk -v p=0 ' /^Line1$/,/^Line4/ { p=1;if(/Line1/ || /Line4/) p=0}p ' navnath.txt
Line3
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want *between*, exclude the beginning and ending, an easy way is (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^Line1$/,/^Line4$/{/^Line1$/d;/^Line4$/d;p}'
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file
Line1A
Line2
Line1
Line3
Line4

$ sed -n '/^Line1$/,/^Line4$/{/^Line1$/d;/^Line4$/d;p}' file
Line3
```

BSD sed:

```
sed -n -e '/^Line1$/,/^Line4$/{' -e '/^Line1$/d;/^Line4$/d;p' -e '}'
```

`awk` version:

```
awk '/^Line1$/{s=1;next}/^Line4$/{s=0}s'
```